# PHP Form Button Doesn't Submit; Page Refresh Only

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

This form originally used reCAPTCHA v1 but I have removed the associated code.
I am collecting user registration info to post to MySQL database but the submit button only refreshes the page and does not lead further to the message that there is a confirmation email to follow. The files are accessible and functional but the form itself and the submission does not work.

I have tried to include reCAPTCHA v2 as a replacement and did so successfully but the form still does not submit. I have since removed it. Furthermore, I have removed fields to see if the checkbox for Terms and Conditions is the issue because it doesn't throw an error unlike the other fields if unchecked but that also didn't work. I've reviewed prior questions about PHP form submission issues and all I found was that the button type was incorrect as in not submit but it is the correct type. The database is confirmed connected which is the called for 'config.php'

PHP Code of the Form:

```
$data['PageName']='SIGN UP FOR YOUR FREE ACCOUNT TODAY';
$data['PageFile']='signup';
$data['PageTitle'] = 'Sign Up - GPW'; 

include('../config.php');
require_once('recaptchalib.php');

// Get a key from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
$publickey = "6Ld3c-YSAAAAAIIdQocSje_bq1a7Sti3QymRM5hw";
$privatekey = "6Ld3c-YSAAAAAJqrQBNAR_Qb40Mh4BveQ_q8bjv0";

# the response from reCAPTCHA
$resp = null;
# the error code from reCAPTCHA, if any
$error = null;

if($_SESSION['login']){
    header("Location:{$data['Host']}/members/index.php");
    echo('Logged In');
    exit;
}
if($post['action']=='go')optimize('common');
if($post['send']){
    if(!$post['newuser']){
        $data['Error']='Your username can not be empty.';
    }elseif(verify_username($post['newuser'])){
        $data['Error']='For your username you can use only next letters [A..Z, a..z, 0..9].';
    }elseif(!$post['newpass']){
        $data['Error']='Your password can not be empty.';
    }elseif(strlen($post['newpass'])<$data['PassLen']){
        $data['Error']="Your password must be at least {$data['PassLen']} characters long.";
    }elseif($post['newpass']!=$post['cfmpass']){
        $data['Error']='Your password and confirm should be not different.';
    }elseif($post['newuser']==$post['newpass']){
        $data['Error']='Your password can not be same as your username.';
    }elseif(!$post['newques']){
        $data['Error']='Please enter a valid security question.';
    }elseif(!$post['newansw']){
        $data['Error']='Please enter a valid security answer.';
    }elseif(!$post['newmail']||verify_email($post['newmail'])){
        $data['Error']='Please enter your valid e-mail address.';
   }elseif($data['UseExtRegForm']&&!$post['newfname']){
        $data['Error']='Please enter your first name.';
   }elseif($data['UseExtRegForm']&&!$post['newlname']){
        $data['Error']='Please enter your last name.';
   }elseif($data['UseExtRegForm']&&!$post['newaddress']){
        $data['Error']='Please enter your address.';
   }elseif($data['UseExtRegForm']&&!$post['newcity']){
        $data['Error']='Please enter your city.';
   }elseif($data['UseExtRegForm']&&!$post['newcountry']){
        $data['Error']='Please enter your country.';
   }elseif($data['UseExtRegForm']&&!$post['newzip']){
      $data['Error']='Please enter your postal code.';
   }elseif($data['UseExtRegForm']&&!$post['newphone']){
      $data['Error']='Please enter your telephone number.';
    }elseif($post['terms']!='on'){
        $data['Error']='Please read our Terms and Conditions before signup.';
    }elseif(!is_user_available($post['newuser'])){
        $data['Error']='Sorry but this username already taken.';
    }elseif(!is_mail_available($post['newmail'])){
        $data['Error']='Sorry but this e-mail address already taken.';
    }else{
        if (isset($_POST["recaptcha_response_field"])) {
            $resp = recaptcha_check_answer($privatekey,$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],$_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],$_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
            //print_r($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]);

                if ($resp->is_valid) { 
                    create_confirmation(
                        $post['newuser'],
                        $post['newpass'],
                        $post['newques'],
                        $post['newansw'],
                        $post['newmail'],
                        $post['newfname'],
                        $post['newlname'],
                        $post['newcompany'],
                        $post['newregnum'],
                        $post['newdrvnum'],
                        $post['newaddress'],
                        $post['newcity'],
                        $post['newcountry'],
                        $post['newstate'],
                        $post['newzip'],
                        $post['newphone'],
                        $post['newfax'],
                        get_member_id($_SESSION['sponsor'])
                    );
                    unset($_SESSION['turing']);
                    $data['PostSent']=true;
                }
        } else {
            $error = $resp->error;
        }
    }
}else{
    if($data['UseTuringNumber'])$_SESSION['turing']=gencode();
}
display('members');
?>
```

Comment: For your next questions, please only post relevant code. The whole page's html is not useful at all.

Comment: I can't see the form open tag.

Comment: See update above.

Answer (score 0):

```
type=submit name=send
```

Missing quotes

```
type="submit" name="send"
```

Comment: Can you cleanup all of that whitespace and limit the html yo your form?

Comment: I have limited the HTML to the submit button. Let me know if I should leave a sample field of data entry but they're all the same.

Comment: Having trouble seeing where your form begins and ends. As they said above, where is your <form> tag?

Comment: See update above. I removed it accidentally. Full HTML code above but removed the redundant fields of entry.

Comment: Where are you opening the <form> and calling the PHP file via a POST method?

Comment: The HTML is purely design. All that is running is the PHP code above and the database is confirmed connected. Sorry for the confusion, can you review the above smaller code? Furthermore, the recaptchalib.php is for the outdated v1. Is there a way to make the code work without it? I've tried removing it but I'm getting errors.